# 'type scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate' is missing from the classpath

Tags: scala, gradle, libgdx

I'm attempting to use two ParRanges (Parallel Ranges) in Scala 2.13.0 to perform an arbitrary operation, but I seem to be missing some dependency and am not sure what it is.

I'm developing a game in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.1.3, using the Libgdx framework v1.9.9, with Gradle for dependency management, in Scala 2.13.0

I have the Scala 2.13.0 SDK in my global libraries, and I've imported these dependencies (among others) into my project in the build.gradle:

```
<... rest of build.gradle file above>

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "scala"

    dependencies {
        compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.0"
        <other dependencies>
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "scala"

    dependencies {
        compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.13.0"
        compile "org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parallel-collections_2.13.0-M2:1.0.2"
        <other dependencies>
    }
}

<... rest of build.gradle file below>
```

Sample code in question is:

```scala
    ParRange(0, Width, 1, true).foreach(x => {
      ParRange(0, Height, 1, true).foreach(y => {
        pixmap.setColor(Math.random().toFloat, Math.random().toFloat, Math.random().toFloat, 1)
        pixmap.drawPixel(x, y)
      })
    })
```

When I attempt to run the program, I get several runtime errors in the same vein:

```
Error:(29, 27) Symbol 'type scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'trait scala.collection.generic.GenericParTemplate'.
Make sure that type GenericTraversableTemplate is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'GenericParTemplate.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of scala.collection.generic.
    ParRange(0, Width, 1, true).foreach(x => {
```

Also missing are:

```
'type scala.collection.GenIterableLike'
'type scala.collection.Parallel'
'type scala.collection.GenSeqLike'
'type scala.Immutable'
```

I'm having one heck of a time figuring out what dependency I'm supposed to be importing in my build.gradle in order to use the parallel collections.

According to the ScalaDocs for 2.12.1, these should all exist: see https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/generic/GenericTraversableTemplate.html

However, the ScalaDocs for 2.13.0 show that these are all missing: see https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/generic/index.html

Why would the parallel collections for Scala 2.13.0 rely upon classes and traits present in Scala 2.12.1 but not in Scala 2.13.0?

Comment: I reported a bug to the Scala team: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would the parallel collections for Scala 2.13.0 rely upon classes and traits present in Scala 2.12.1 but not in Scala 2.13.0?

Because it isn't a version for 2.13, it's for 2.13.0-M2 (which still had them). https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parallel-collections shows that this version dates from 2017, while 0.2.0 is the actual latest version published for 2.13, despite the version number.